# При запуске ТГ бота магазина, вылетает ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, aiogram, asyncio

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import executor

from config import admin_id
from database import create_db
from load_all import bot


async def on_shutdown(dp):
await bot.close()


async def on_startup(dp):
await create_db()
await bot.send_message(admin_id, "Я запущен!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
from admin_panel import dp
from handlers import dp

executor.start_polling(dp, on_shutdown=on_shutdown, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: Какая ошибка вылетает?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Professional\Desktop\telegram-bot-lessons-master\telegram-bot-lessons-master\lesson-6\app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from config import admin_id

Comment: File "C:\Users\Professional\Desktop\telegram-bot-lessons-master\telegram-bot-lessons-master\lesson-6\config.py", line 8, in <module>
    admin_id = int(os.getenv("ADMIN_ID"))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Эти ошибки вот высыпаются по порядку

Comment: Выглядит так, как будто у вас переменная ADMIN_ID не может быть воспринята как INT, как у вас выглядит сама переменная в окружении?

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать ее при помощи os.environ['ADMIN_ID'], скорее всего в этом проблема

Comment: admin_id = int(os.getenv("ADMIN_ID"))
запрос к файлу example.env в котором указан ADMIN_ID=мой id